# Angular Error and Timeout Factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, error-handling, factory

Throughout my project I have a piece of code that performs CRUD with Parse.com via the REST API. I would like to insert a function in the error handler that is a universal (project wide) error function.

I have considered a factory / service or possibly passing something via `$rootScope`.

Secondly I would like to wrap all my api calls in a timeout function so that if there is no response in a certain time then I can notify the user with a useful notification.

```
ParseFactory.provider('Programme').getAll().success(function(data){
     $scope.programmes = data.results;

  }).error(function(response){
    $ionicPopup.alert({
    title: 'Unable to load - Please check your connection '
    });

  });
```

Any examples of how to best achieve this would be greatly received.

=== EDIT - adding ParseFactory Code ===

```
.factory('ParseFactory',['$http','PARSE_CREDENTIALS',function($http,PARSE_CREDENTIALS){
    var baseUrl = 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/';
        return {
            provider:function(type) {
                var userQuery = {'userId': Parse.User.current().id};
                return {
                    getAll:function(){
                        return $http.get(getUrl(type),getUserParams());
                    },
                    get:function(id){
                        return $http.get(getUrl(type)+id,getParams());
                    },
                    create:function(data){
                        return $http.post(getUrl(type),data,getParams());
                    },
                    edit:function(id,data){
                        return $http.put(getUrl(type)+id,data,getParams());
                    },
                    delete:function(id){
                        return $http.delete(getUrl(type)+id,getParams());
                    }
                }
                function getUrl(type) {
                    return baseUrl+type;
                }

                function getParams() {
                    return {
                            headers:{
                                'X-Parse-Application-Id': PARSE_CREDENTIALS.APP_ID,
                                'X-Parse-REST-API-Key':PARSE_CREDENTIALS.REST_API_KEY,
                                'X-Parse-Session-Token': PARSE_CREDENTIALS.PARSE_SESSION,
                                'Content-Type':'application/json'
                            }      
                    }    
                }
            }
        }

    }])
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Regarding single error handler function which shows the ionicPopup:

You can emit an event using `$rootScope.$emit` from the error callback functions. 
You can listen to all those events using `$rootScope.$on` in either `run()` method or in a `factory` and it will show the `$ionicPopup`

In your error handler:

```
$rootScope.$emit('errorEvent',
           {"message" : "Pass your custom message here", "errorObject": errorObject} 
);
```

In your `event` listener

```
app.run(function($ionicPopup) {
    $rootScope.$on("errorEvent", function(event, data) {
      // you can access that here
       $ionicPopup.alert({
            title: data.message
        });
   });
});
```

Update:

For the timeout option, in your `getParams()` function add timeout config property

```
 function getParams() {
     return {
         timeout: 18000, // adjust this value
         headers: {
             'X-Parse-Application-Id': PARSE_CREDENTIALS.APP_ID,
             'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': PARSE_CREDENTIALS.REST_API_KEY,
             'X-Parse-Session-Token': PARSE_CREDENTIALS.PARSE_SESSION,
             'Content-Type': 'application/json'
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Ok that's kinda cool. Can I pass a variable depending on what I want the popup to say? Or include the returned error from Parse?

Comment: Yes, you can. Will add a sample

Comment: @Taylorsuk added an example for you :)

Comment: Do you have any ideas on timeout functions?

Comment: Share parsefactory code. In case you are using $http then you can set the timeout property in that with the time limit

Comment: In your getParams() function, add timeout : 5000 in that returned object.

Comment: Updated answer with that :)